# Npm start errors Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'serialport

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I got an error when I'm trying to run my angular app.
I have installed nodejs,python,electron but can't run the app...
I write "npm start" command in CMD but I got an error like this:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\string-desktop>npm start
npm WARN invalid config registry=""
npm WARN invalid config Must be a full url with 'http://'
npm WARN invalid config registry=""
npm WARN invalid config Must be a full url with 'http://'

> ExhangeDesktop@0.1.0 start C:\xampp\htdocs\string-desktop
> electron . --enable-logging
    [11016:0313/090858.182:INFO:CONSOLE(8)] "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.", source: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/string-desktop/src/thirdparty/less-1.3.3.min.js (8)
    [11016:0313/090858.288:INFO:CONSOLE(8)] "less: parsed file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/string-desktop/src/less/stringdesktop.less successfully.", source: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/string-desktop/src/thirdparty/less-1.3.3.min.js (8)
    [11016:0313/090858.328:INFO:CONSOLE(8)] "less: css for file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/string-desktop/src/less/stringdesktop.less generated in 135ms", source: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/string-desktop/src/thirdparty/less-1.3.3.min.js (8)
    [11016:0313/090858.329:INFO:CONSOLE(8)] "less: css generated in 135ms", source: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/string-desktop/src/thirdparty/less-1.3.3.min.js (8)
    [11016:0313/090858.542:VERBOSE1:CONSOLE(7847)] "Main._createAppUI: 107.35302734375ms", source: chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/shell.js (7847)
    [11016:0313/090858.666:VERBOSE1:CONSOLE(7847)] "Main._showAppUI: 121.22802734375ms", source: chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/shell.js (7847)
    [11016:0313/090858.765:VERBOSE1:CONSOLE(7847)] "Main._initializeTarget: 51.9619140625ms", source: chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/shell.js (7847)
    [11016:0313/090858.796:INFO:CONSOLE(604)] "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'serialport'", source: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js (604)
    [11016:0313/090858.812:INFO:CONSOLE(604)] "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'iconv-lite'", source: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js (604)
    [11016:0313/090858.817:INFO:CONSOLE(18)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined", source: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/string-desktop/src/utils/Sync.js (18)
    [11016:0313/090858.822:INFO:CONSOLE(4)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined", source: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/string-desktop/src/utils/EcrCommands.js (4)
    [11016:0313/090858.827:INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined", source: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/string-desktop/src/utils/Ecr.js (3)
    [11016:0313/090858.828:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined", source: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/string-desktop/src/utils/Updater.js (1)
    [11016:0313/090858.955:WARNING:CONSOLE(184)] "%cElectron Security Warning (Insecure Content-Security-Policy)", source: C:\xampp\htdocs\string-desktop\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\renderer\security-warnings.js (184)
    [11016:0313/090858.977:VERBOSE1:CONSOLE(7847)] "Main._lateInitialization: 2.093994140625ms", source: chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/shell.js (7847)
    [11016:0313/090859.346:INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined", source: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/string-desktop/src/controllers/Widget.js (3)
    [11016:0313/090859.354:INFO:CONSOLE(4)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined", source: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/string-desktop/src/controllers/TableSelector.js (4)
    [11016:0313/090859.363:INFO:CONSOLE(31)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined", source: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/string-desktop/src/controllers/Operation.js (31)
    [11016:0313/090859.366:INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined", source: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/string-desktop/src/controllers/Model.js (3)
    [11016:0313/090859.372:INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined", source: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/string-desktop/src/controllers/CurrencyStock.js (3)
    [11016:0313/090859.374:INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined", source: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/string-desktop/src/controllers/Transition.js (3)
    [11016:0313/090859.377:INFO:CONSOLE(9)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined", source: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/string-desktop/src/controllers/DayFinish.js (9)
    [11016:0313/090859.379:INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined", source: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/string-desktop/src/controllers/Controller.js (3)
    [11016:0313/090859.383:INFO:CONSOLE(4)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined", source: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/string-desktop/src/controllers/Config.js (4)
    [11016:0313/090859.393:INFO:CONSOLE(66)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined", source: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/string-desktop/src/controllers/Home.js (66)
    [11016:0313/090859.395:INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined", source: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/string-desktop/src/controllers/Login.js (3)
    [11016:0313/090859.398:INFO:CONSOLE(4)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined", source: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/string-desktop/src/controllers/DateChanger.js (4)
    [11016:0313/090859.405:INFO:CONSOLE(84)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined", source: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/string-desktop/src/controllers/Chatter.js (84)
    [11016:0313/090859.408:INFO:CONSOLE(4)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined", source: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/string-desktop/src/controllers/EcrDebug.js (4)
    [11016:0313/090859.410:INFO:CONSOLE(59)] "Uncaught TypeError: up.App is not a constructor", source: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/string-desktop/src/init.js (59)
    [11016:0313/090859.423:INFO:CONSOLE(184)] "%cElectron Security Warning (Insecure Content-Security-Policy)", source: C:\xampp\htdocs\string-desktop\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\renderer\security-warnings.js (184)
```

Could someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the wrong command run the angular application you need to use the following command to run the angular application.

Navigate to your project directory and run the following command.

> ng serve

Hope this will help!

Comment: This command not work for me.I got this error:  "'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: which version of angular you are using?

Comment: so you also need to install angular-cli before running angular application

Comment: I have to install angular-cli in my app folder ?

Comment: no it should install at global level using this command npm install -g @angular/cli

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!
I deleted node_modules folder and reinstalled npm and now it's all okay. Thanks to all!